# How can you get STDIN input to a WSH script using cscript.exe?

Tags: wsh

I'm trying to use WSH in place of DOS/Batch files.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: STDIN/`"Thanks for the input!"`; pun intended? :D

Comment: aww you caught me lol =]

Comment: powershell replaces VBScript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use WScript.StdIn

```
var input=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
```